# In MVC can I return the json data to the view which formate like a two-dimensional array?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In the view I want to get the json data like this:

```
 [{"name":"NewWork",
  "data":[{"\/Date(1398787200000)\/",196},
           {"\/Date(1398009600000)\/",62},
           {"\/Date(1397836800000)\/",65}]
  },
 {"name":"BeiJing",
 "data":[{"\/Date(1398787200000)\/",106},
         {"\/Date(1398700800000)\/",100},
         {"\/Date(1398441600000)\/",61},
         {"\/Date(1398355200000)\/",86}]
  }]
```

So in the controller I define the class like these,and return `List<ViewModelCityData>` but the return data format is not what I want.How can I change the controller ViewModelCityData?And the other question,in the view my json `data` need to be order by `X`，if I sort them in the controller,why do they not order in the view?I have to sort them again in the view.

```
 public class ViewModelCityData
{
   public string name { get; set; }
  public List<Point> data { get; set; }
}

public class Point
{
    public DateTime X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}


 [{"name":"NewWork",
  "data":[{"X":"\/Date(1398787200000)\/","Y":196},
          {"X":"\/Date(1398009600000)\/","Y":62},
          {"X":"\/Date(1397836800000)\/","Y":65}]
        },
   {"name":"BeiJing",
   "data":[{"X":"\/Date(1398787200000)\/","Y":106},
           {"X":"\/Date(1398700800000)\/","Y":100},
           {"X":"\/Date(1398441600000)\/","Y":61},
           {"X":"\/Date(1398355200000)\/","Y":86}]}]
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1***

If you can live with **{Key:Value}** format than you can accomplish this by implementing a custom converter.

```
public class PointsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private DateTime _epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var point = (Point) value;

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName(string.Format("/Date({0})/", GetMilliseconds(point.X)));
        writer.WriteRawValue(point.Y.ToString());
        writer.WriteEnd();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
                                    JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (Point);
    }

    private double GetMilliseconds(DateTime date)
    {
        var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(date.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - _epoch.Ticks);
        return timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

and pass it to converter:

```
var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(models, Formatting.Indented, new PointsConverter());
```

**Result**:

```
[{"name": "Tiraspol",
  "data": [{"/Date(1401188096166,27)/": 10},
           {"/Date(1401191696166,27)/": 20}]
  },
 {"name": "Limassol",
  "data": [{"/Date(1401195296166,27)/": 10},
           {"/Date(1401198896166,27)/": 20}]
  }
]
```

**Solution 2**

if you can live with **[X,Y]** format (*instead of {X,Y}*), than you can write them as an array. For this scenario use next code in converter:

```
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var point = (Point) value;

        writer.WriteStartArray();
        writer.WriteValue(string.Format("/Date({0})/", GetMilliseconds(point.X)));
        writer.WriteValue(point.Y.ToString());
        writer.WriteEnd();
    }
```

**Result**:

```
[{"name": "Tiraspol",
  "data": [["/Date(1401188096166,27)/": 10],
           ["/Date(1401191696166,27)/": 20]]
  },
 {"name": "Limassol",
  "data": [["/Date(1401195296166,27)/": 10},
           ["/Date(1401198896166,27)/": 20]]
  }
]
```

**Solution 3**

Pass X,Y as elements of array.

```
var jsonReady = models.Select(x => new
{
    x.name,
    data = x.data.Select(point => new object[] {point.X, point.Y}).ToArray()
});
var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonReady, Formatting.Indented, new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
```

You will get the same result as in solution 2. Not pretty nice solution but you got the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
public List<Point> data { get; set; }
```

Try this:

```
public Dictionary<DateTime, int> data { get; set; }
```

> And the other question,in the view my json data need to be order by X，if I sort them in the controller,why do they not order in the view?I have to sort them again in the view.

You're not showing the sort code you use, but I find it likely that you're not actually changing the list. People often do this:

```
list.OrderBy(e => e.X);
```

... when they should do this:

```
list = list.OrderBy(e => e.X);
```

Comment: Yes,I try to use Dictionary<DateTime, int>,but in MVC,it show that Dictionary can not be serialized.It means I can not change List<Point> data to Dictionary<DateTime, int> data.

Comment: @Lyly: Then the real problem is just figuring out how to get it to serialize Dictionaries. Have you tried using JSON.NET? It's so much better than the built-in .NET serializer that it's become the de facto standard these days.

Comment: according to what you suggest,it return the format almost what I want.But I think the data format is still wrong.'[{"data":{"2014-05-01T00:00:00":94,"2014-04-30T00:00:00":109,"2014-04-29T00:00:00":92,"2014-04-24T00:00:00":120},"name":"NewYork"},{"data":{"2014-04-30T00:00:00":196,"2014-04-21T00:00:00":62},"name":"BeiJing"}]'

Comment: use `dictionary` and `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` I think the datetime formate is change,and I hope the data with many object which split with `{}`,but now it has only one `{}` and split with `,`

Comment: @Lyly: You can get the date format you're asking for by [specifying the serializer](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net). JSON.NET used to use that format, but it has since adopted the newer standard. Also see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If `Dictionary<DateTime, int>` do not work,try to use `int[][]` 
Instead of this:

```
public List<Point> data { get; set; }
```

Try this:

```
public int[][] data { get; set; }
```